# Trying to find out which Android control this is?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android so please bear with me...

Can someone tell which what the name of this control is in Android studio, I have been trying to google it but i just cant seem to find it!?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is at the top of the screen, it would be a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout). That usually sits below the Toolbar and is used along with a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) to change the displayed fragments below it. When you link the two, it lets the user change view by either clicking on the tab, or with a swipe gesture.

If it was at the bottom of the screen, it could be a [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView).